# Use normal case in MahApps.Metro Expander controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

In version 1.5 of MahApps.Metro, the default style of the `Expander` control has all characters in its header be uppercase by default. How does one change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guided by [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972090/mahapps-how-to-disable-automatic-uppercase-of-default-button) which deals with the similar question for `Button`s (whose behaviour is similar, but not quite the same), the [source code for the control](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.MetroMahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Expander.xaml), and IntelliSense, it turns out that one can modify `ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing` to obtain the desired effect. In particular, the following style gives an `Expander` that is identical to the Metro styled one, but with normal casing:

```
<Style x:Key="MetroExpanderWithNormalCase" TargetType="Expander" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroExpander}">
    <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing" Value="Normal"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Your [source code for the control](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.MetroMahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Expander.xaml) link is broken.